# Shall I use the old receipt-data when revalidating iOS Auto-Renewable Subscriptions?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

1. Support user purchased the iOS Auto-Renewable Subscriptions on 1st Jan, and valid for 1 month
2. Today is 1st Feb, user has not cancelled the subscriptions,
3. Shall my backend server use the old receipt-data (during the 1st purchase) to validate the purchase from Apple so to extends the subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You should use the original receipt, or any other receipt you have stored, that is from that user and relates to this specific subscription.  During verification, Apple will send you the latest receipt for that subscription.  You could store that new receipt and use that to validate the subscription in the future.  But you can also just keep on using that original receipt to verify an account.